# Array Minimum Range from copying array items

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, copy

I am copying array items from another array in the following way

```
    arrayOne = [resultArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, MIN(3, resultArray.count))];
```

it copies 3 items in array one what if i want items starting from index 4 to 5 i have six itmes in array

```
    arrayTwo = [resultArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(4, MIN(5, resultArray.count))];
```

then it gives error and not working

Comment: array has 6 items i want 0 1 2 in arrayOne and 345 in arrayTwo how to do this please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will give you indexes 3, 4, and 5:

```
if (resultArray.count >= 6) {
    arrayTwo = [resultArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 3)];
} else {
    // not enough to get desired values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
arrayOne = [resultArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3)];
arrayTwo = [resultArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(3,3)];
```